# Creating a calendar app using MEAN that listen to changes

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm thinking about starting a kind of calendar web app for me to practise and improve my web development skills. I've been designing the structure and technologies to use and finally I decided to use the MEAN stack. I've arrived to a problem: I would like to "auto update" the angular front-end in case new events are added to the calendar ( for example if a new event is added from another tab o even another computer and probably in a future from a smartphone app). How would be the proper way to get this updates? I was thinking about using the "collection.watch()" method from mongodb to detect when the document associated with the account has changed and then socket.io, but , should I do that on the server side or in the client side? And then if I do it on the server side, how do I update the angular view?
Well, I hope I've been clear enough and that I'm not that confused that what I'm planning has no sense.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are on the right path with your thoughts. You can use socket io for this project. I would suggest you follow the example of the chat app on socket IOs webpage:

[Socket IO Chat app](https://socket.io/get-started/chat)

Basically socket io is the server-side technology:

**NODEJS:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
}); 

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Which lets the browser connect on a websocket connection to the server. The websocket connection allows for browser to communicate in real-time.

**FRONT-END**

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using [Meteor](https://meteor.com) for this. This type of server -> client updates are exactly what it was designed for. The below example assumes blaze as the rendering engine, but it works just as well with react, vue or angular.

You'd have a server file:

```
const events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
Meteor.publish("events", function(some, arguments) {
   return events.find({some mongo query});
});
```

on the client side, you'd have some JS code:

```
const events = new Mongo.Collection("events");
Meteor.subscribe("events", some, arguments);

Template.someTemplate.helpers({
  events() {
    return events.find();
  }
});
```

and some HTML code:

```
<template name="someTemplate">
{{#each event in events}}
 <!-- do something with the event -->
{{/each}}
</template>
```